# Close multiple Folders concurrently

Tags: finder

My computer opens many folders through obscure codes.
Instead of closing them one by one, I tried to force quit Finder.

However, there's only `relauch` option.
[image]

After relaunching, those folders still exist.

How to resolve such a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>W</kbd>  will close all windows.